# Snakeyaml to convert yaml to pojo

Tags: java, converters, pojo, snakeyaml

I want to load a list of POJO from my yaml file. Is it possible for me to do that using snake yaml?

my yaml file looks something like this --

```
- pty1:val1
  pty2:val2

- pty1:val1
  pty2:val2
```

And my pojo -

```
class pojo {
  String pty1;
  String pty2;
}
```

Snakeyaml documentation does say to use loadAs() but that loads a single element. Can I load list of such elements with automatic type binding?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use `yaml.load(yamlString)`? As I can see here https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Loading_YAML it should help you.

Comment: It doesnt work... It loads it as a list of linked hash map. Probably should I add tags for snakeyaml to recognize that its a java bean?

Comment: As you wrote you should load pojos to list and work on it. BTW you can also use `loadAll` method.

Answer (score 3):

I've started using [Jackson's YAML format plugin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) for serializing and deserializing YAML.
Quite friendly.

Comment: I could have found an answer here but instead found a link. Guess I still appreciate the partial answer..

Answer (score -2):

One way to achieve this is to create a class that contains a list of POJO.

```
class POJOList {
    List<pojo> pojoList;
    public POJOList(List<pojo> pojoList) {
        this.pojoList = pojoList;
    }
}
```

You can then read the yaml file under the resources folder as:

```
InputStream in = ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("pojolist.yaml");
POJOList pojoList = yaml.loadAs(in, POJOList.class);
```